# attempted WUBI install corrupted Vista

Tags: partitioning, wubi, windows-vista

Tried to install WUBI through Google Chrome on my Vista machine. Got through the usual warning about running new software, selected "continue" and waited for a prompt about where to install WUBI. Never got one...waited about 30 minutes (computer still running fine)...decided to reboot and try again. OOOOOPS. Was not able to reboot Vista. Ouch. When I run a Vista recovery CD it tells me there is an "X:" drive on what used to be my C: drive and it cannot find a Vista install to recover. Anyone seen this ? It is making me very happy...

THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

That's vista all right....

Read this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

"with great power, comes great responsibility"
-sudo